# matplotlib onPick Event registering twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

As part of a larger project I am updating a graph on matplotlib embedded in Pyqt5. I have an onpick event that adds and removes annotation to a scatter point. After I updated my plot in a fashion similar to below the onPick feature registers twice. There is something underlying that is not getting removed correctly. I was wondering what I might clear, besides the figure, that would correct my issue.

Simple Example Highlighting the issue:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class plot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    self.figure = plt.figure()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

    self.Layout = QVBoxLayout()

    self.xarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    self.yarray = [6,7,5,4,2,1]

    update_btn = QPushButton("Update Plot", self)
    self.Layout.addWidget(update_btn, 1)
    update_btn.clicked.connect(self.updateplot)

    self.createplot()

    self.setLayout(self.Layout)

def updateplot(self):

    self.xarray = [6,7,5,3,2,1]
    self.figure.clear()
    self.createplot()

def createplot(self):

    ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.grid()
    val = self.displayval(ax)
    self.plot = ax.plot(self.xarray, self.yarray,'o', marker = 'o', c= 'b', picker = 5)[0]

    self.Layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 2)
    self.canvas.draw()

def displayval(self, ax):
    def onPick(event):
        print("connecting")
        plot = event.artist

        xval = plot.get_xdata()
        yval = plot.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind

        if xval[ind].size > 1 or yval[ind].size > 1: return

        xy = (xval[ind][0], yval[ind][0])

        ann = ax.annotate('(%f , %f)' % xy, xy= xy)

        self.figure.canvas.draw()

    self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onPick)
    return onPick

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appl = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = plot()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(appl.exec_())
```

Note: I have tried updating the axis values with something like

```
ax.set_xaxis()
```

However this does not render the data correctly in my program, therefore an alternative answer would be preferred.

Comment: I think each time you update the plot, a new pick_event is registered. So if you update it once, you will have onPick called twice, if you updated it twice you will have it called three times and so on. You would need to make sure to only register it once, independend on the update function.

Comment: I agree with @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. You have to disconnect the signal/slot when you clear the plot, such as just after `figure.clear()`, or before connecting it inside `displayval()`.

Comment: @bnacker Clearing the signal/event queue in `displayval()` is a great idea for a workaround. I will see if i can figure out how to do that. However, i don't this it solves the root of the problem of why it's registering two actions on the canvas after clearing the figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm sorry I must be unclear. you said that updating the plot causes a new pick event to register. and this happens every time the plot is updated. which is my issue. what i don't understand is why this would happen. what about updating my plot causes this pick event repetition?

Comment: Click of update button calls `updateplot`. `updateplot` calls `createplot`. `createplot` calls `displayval`. `displayval` registers a new pick_event. Hence, each time you press the button, a new event is registered (plus the event from the initial plot).

Comment: I completely understand now. thank you for your help! if you post this comment as an answer I will happily accept it.

Comment: Because I do not really know what you eventually want to achieve I cannot give you a conclusive answer. You may answer your own question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Solution to the issue. Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for explaining why the issue was occurring. From there I was able to fix the problem. Once updated the on click annotation only occurs once. The solution is only to call `displayval` once and change `ax` to 'self.ax' and update the object variable.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class plot(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.Layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.xarray = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
        self.yarray = [6,7,5,4,2,1]
        self.init_trigger = True

        update_btn = QPushButton("Update Plot", self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(update_btn, 1)
        update_btn.clicked.connect(self.updateplot)

        self.createplot()

        self.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def updateplot(self):

        self.xarray = [6,7,5,3,2,1]
        self.figure.clear()
        self.createplot()

    def createplot(self):


        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.ax.grid()
        if self.init_trigger: val = self.displayval()
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.xarray, self.yarray,'o', marker = 'o', c= 'b', picker = 5)[0]

        self.Layout.addWidget(self.canvas, 2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.init_trigger = False

    def displayval(self):
        def onPick(event):
            print("connecting")
            plot = event.artist

            xval = plot.get_xdata()
            yval = plot.get_ydata()
            ind = event.ind

            if xval[ind].size > 1 or yval[ind].size > 1: return

            xy = (xval[ind][0], yval[ind][0])

            ann = self.ax.annotate('(%f , %f)' % xy, xy= xy)

            self.figure.canvas.draw()

        self.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onPick)
        return onPick

if __name__ == '__main__':
    appl = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = plot()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(appl.exec_())
```